# Samba share on Google Compute Engine (GCE VPC)

Tags: google-compute-engine, vpc

Is there any fundamental reason why I cannot expose samba shares on a Google Compute Engine's network (VPC)?  I'm fairly confident I have the firewall rules set up correctly (ports 137-139, 445, TCP & UDP) and internal testing with smbclient shows the server is up and running.

Would google block traffic due to some security policy that I am not aware of?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a home network? Some ISPs block these ports to prevent file sharing. Test from your office network to compare. Google Cloud does not block these ports. Only via the VPC firewall which you can configure. You could create a new VPC, launch an instance in the new VPC and verify connectivity and SAMBA share access for testing purposes.

Comment: That was it. Thank you!